How to Merge 3 band RGB images with depth band to make it to four band image
So I am working on a dataset where I have three band RGB images of potatoes and seperate depth band (not specific for each image). I want to merge both to make a four band image. The resolution of both of these are different so cannot directly merge them through numpy. How do I do it??
I have tried numpy concatenation, but nothing worked. I have also followed this tutorial as well
Intel RealSense - Align depth and color in two numpy arrays
